# Is it a good idea to use ASIHTTPRequest library with three20?

Tags: iphone, three20, asihttprequest

Was wondering if it was a good idea to intergrate ASIHTTPRequest framework for HTTP requests for REST while using three20. three20 has TTURLRequest.

Answer (score 4):

I do in my app because it is much more powerful than TTURLRequest for some things.  In my apps, I use TTURLRequest for basic things like http GET's, but I use ASIHTTPRequest for downloading large pieces of data because they offer file resuming and downloading directly to disk.